Cannot connect to Render Postgresql database
I can connect to the Render database using DBeaver, but get the following error when using Postman:

  // Fetch items from the backend
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://dpg-cqri988gph6c739vmtc0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com/api/items")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setItems(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data:", error));
  }, []);

"GET https://dpg-cqri988gph6c739vmtc0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com/api/items
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.227.164.209:443
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.31.1
Accept: /
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ca1892f1-5962-4b45-9146-f370da0ec61f
Host: dpg-cqri988gph6c739vmtc0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive"

Tried using both thhp and https
Both Thunderclient and Postman gives the same error


I work at Render and also used to work at Postman.
In DBeaver, are you using the "external database url" that we provide from the Render dashboard? If so, that connection string will look something like postgresql://username:password@hostname/databasename?sslmode=require and not start with an https:// protocol.
If you need a web admin interface, I'd recommend looking into a Docker container version of pgDash or something similar. We don't currently offer any web-based interface, nor API layer to your database data.
